бот не отвечает в беседе. aiogram python telegram/
есть код. команда /start работает как в лс бота так и в беседе. а вот второй хэндлер в беседе не работает, хотя в лс с ботом отвечает как надо. при этом в логах никаких ошибок.
код ниже
bot = Bot(token='типо токен')
# Диспетчер
dp = Dispatcher()
@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def starting(message: types.message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "привет")
@dp.message(lambda message: message.text == "пока" )
async def loh(message: types.message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "бб")


попробуй магический фильтр F
from aioram import F

@dp.message(F.text == "пока")
async def loh(message: types.message):
    await message.answer(message.chat.id, "бб")


не в этом дело было. я забыл, что бот  читает сообщения только если обратиться к нему через @ или командой "/". лямбда работает отлично, про фильтр знаю, но использовать не вижу смысла. спасибо за попытку помочь
